# Linux firewall policies not working as expected when connecting two VPNs

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, firewall

I have to VPNs joint together with an route:

```
ip route add 10.6.0.0/24 via 10.6.1.2
```

All Servers on both networks are able to ping each other. However I cannot connect to a service from the client `10.6.1.3` to `10.6.0.1` port `6443`. The firewall on the VPN server `10.6.1.1` tells me:

```
[UFW BLOCK] IN=wg0 OUT=wg0 MAC= SRC=10.6.1.3 DST=10.6.0.1 LEN=64 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=63 ID=0 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=64637 DPT=6443 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0
```

the ufw rules look like this:

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp (OpenSSH)           ALLOW IN    Anywhere
51820/udp                  ALLOW IN    Anywhere
443/tcp                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere
Anywhere on wg0            ALLOW IN    Anywhere
6443                       ALLOW IN    10.6.0.0/16
10.6.0.1 6443              ALLOW IN    10.6.1.3
22/tcp (OpenSSH (v6))      ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
51820/udp (v6)             ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
Anywhere (v6) on wg0       ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)

Anywhere                   ALLOW OUT   Anywhere on wg0
10.6.0.0/24 6443           ALLOW OUT   10.6.1.0/24
Anywhere (v6)              ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6) on wg0
```

I am unable to find out what is missing, so that I can connect to the port `6443`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured that I had to setup ufw routing options as well.

```
ufw route allow in on wg0 out on wg0
ufw route allow out on wg0 in on wg0
```

that did the trick for me.